# Stop CSS from overriding each other

Tags: css, sass

So I have a div with a className items-wrapper and I'm using some media queries to make my page responsive. The problem is that these styles I've put override each other and end up not working at all. How can I prevent this from happening? A lot of solution out there have not been helpful to me.
my class Selector

```
return (
            <div className="items-wrapper">
             {display}  
            </div>
        );
```

SCSS:

```
.items-wrapper {
    padding-top: 98px;
    animation: slideUp 300ms linear;
    animation-delay: 150ms;
    @media (max-width: 991px){
        padding-top: 68px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 480px){
        padding-top: 52px;
    }
}
```

The generated CSS:

```
.items-wrapper {
  padding-top: 98px;
  animation: slideUp 300ms linear;
  animation-delay: 150ms; }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .items-wrapper {
      padding-top: 68px; } }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .items-wrapper {
      padding-top: 52px; } }
```

only the last padding-top property works the rest of the properties don't. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: try to re-read you CSS to see how it working and also check the Google dev tools to see when and how they are not working

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this css - the override has to come from somewhere else